# Livewire method not triggering in view

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm working on a Laravel project with Livewire, and I have a component where I want to trigger a method called filterRows when a link is clicked.

However, the method doesn't seem to be triggering, and I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Here's the relevant code snippet from my Livewire view:

```php
<!-- Livewire view code -->
    <div>
        <li class="relative" x-data="{ open: false }">
            <button class="relative align-middle rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline-purple"
                @click="open = !open" @keydown.escape="open = false" @click.away="open = false" aria-label="Notifications"
                aria-haspopup="true">
                <svg class="w-5 h-5" aria-hidden="true" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                    <path
                        d="M10 2a6 6 0 00-6 6v3.586l-.707.707A1 1 0 004 14h12a1 1 0 00.707-1.707L16 11.586V8a6 6 0 00-6-6zM10 18a3 3 0 01-3-3h6a3 3 0 01-3 3z">
                    </path>
                </svg>
                <!-- Notification badge -->
                @if ($notificationsCounts->count() > 0)
                    <span aria-hidden="true"
                        class="absolute -top-1 -right-1 inline-flex w-3 h-3   bg-red-600 border-2 border-white rounded-full dark:border-gray-800  text-white animate-pulse">
                    </span>
                @endif
            </button>
          
            <template  x-if="open" @keydown.escape="open = false"  @click.away="open = false">
                <ul x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-150"          x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100"
                    x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0"
                    class="absolute right-0 w-56 p-2 mt-2 space-y-2 text-gray-600 bg-white border border-gray-100 rounded-md shadow-md dark:text-gray-300 dark:border-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-700">
                   
                    @foreach ($notifications as $notification)                   
                        <li class="flex">
                            <a class="inline-flex items-center justify-between w-full px-2 py-1 text-sm font-semibold transition-colors duration-150 rounded-md hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-800 dark:hover:bg-gray-800 dark:hover:text-gray-200"
                                href="#" {{-- wire:key="'notif'- $notif->id " --}} 
                                wire:key="'{{ 'notif-' . $notification->id }}"
                                wire:click.prevent="filterRows('{{ $notification->model }}', '{!! $notification->id !!}' )"
                                >
                                <span>{{ class_basename($notification->model) }}</span>
                                <span
                                    class="inline-flex items-center justify-center px-2 py-1 text-xs font-bold leading-none text-red-600 bg-red-100 rounded-full dark:text-red-100 dark:bg-red-600">
                                    {{ $notification->message }}
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </template>
        </li>       
    </div>
```

the view is included on the navbar as component

```
 <livewire:notifications  />
```

And here's the relevant code snippet from my Livewire component:

```
<?php  
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Notification;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Notifications extends Component
{
    public $notifs;
    public $selectedModel;
    public $notificationsCounts;

   

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->refreshNotifications();
    }

    public function refreshNotifications()
    {
        $this->notificationsCounts = Notification::select('model', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as count'))
            ->where('is_read', 0)
            ->where('user_id', Auth::id())
            ->groupBy('model')
            ->get();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $this->notifs = Notification::where('is_read', 0)
            ->where('user_id', Auth::id())
            ->get();

        return view('livewire.notifications', [
            'notifications' => $this->notifs,
            'notificationsCounts' => $this->notificationsCounts,
        ]);
    }

    public function filterRows($model, $id)
    {
        $this->selectedModel = $model;

        // Update the is_read field to 1 for the corresponding model
        Notification::where('model', $model)
            ->where('user_id', Auth::id())
            ->update(['is_read' => 1]);

        // Refresh the notifications data
        $this->refreshNotifications();
        
        // Perform any other filtering logic or redirect as needed
    }
}
```

I've verified that Livewire is set up correctly in my project, and I have other Livewire components working as expected.data is displayed normaly (

```php
<span>{{ class_basename($notif->model) }}</span>)
```

However, in this particular case, the filterRows method is not being triggered.

Am I missing something in my Livewire view or component code? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `x-if` directive in `Alpine.js` conditionally renders or removes the entire element and its contents from the `DOM` based on the truthiness of the provided expression. When the expression evaluates to true, the element and its contents are rendered. When the expression evaluates to false, the element and its contents are removed from the `DOM`.

In this case, the use of the `<template>` element with the `x-if` directive caused the element and its contents to be removed from the `DOM` when the open variable was false. As a result, the link within the element couldn't trigger the `filterRows` method because it didn't exist in the `DOM`.

To resolve this issue, you can replace the `<template>` element with a `<div>` element and use the `x-show` directive instead. The `x-show` directive toggles the visibility of the element by manipulating the `CSS` display property, allowing the element to remain in the `DOM` even when it's hidden. With the `<div>` element and the `x-show` directive, the link is always present in the `DOM` and can trigger the `filterRows` method, regardless of its visibility.

By making this change, the issue with the `filterRows` method not being triggered when the element is hidden is resolved, ensuring consistent behavior and functionality in your component.
Thanks to `stackoverflow` & `ChatGPT's` help.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Either it's a typo or you're miraculously not getting an exception for your `wire:key`, as the dash is outside the string and not concatted:

```
wire:key="'notif'- $notif->id "

should be

wire:key="'notif-' . $notif->id"
```

In the case your `$notif->id` isn't numeric, you should ensure it's in quotes:

```
wire:click.prevent="filterRows('{{ $notif->id }}')"
```

Besides the fact you have a `li` without parent (`ol`/`ul`/), your HTML looks fine.

Comment: The problem persists, as there are no errors displayed on the console, and the method is not being triggered.

Comment: No missing `@livewireScripts` or `@livewireStyles`?

Comment: Perhaps review the OP question and update your answer to improve it for details on "Either it's a typo or "